# jqplot horizontal stacked bar chart with bars from right-to-left

Tags: jqplot

My **horizontal stacked bar chart** works well, but I want the **DIRECTION** of the horizontal bars to be from **RIGHT-TO-LEFT**, and **NOT** from **LEFT-TO-RIGHT**.  This includes wanting the line labels to be on the right, and not on the left.

Any thoughts?

What I have:
[image: The zero is on the left, with the 18 on the right....]

What I want:
[image: The zero is on the right, with the 18 on the left (sorry its upside down, hacking this image together....)....]

Comment: Just a quick answer (I haven't tested it) :
In order to have 18 on left and 0 on right you can maybe specify the min and max value of your xaxis.
If you want the line labels to be on the right try to put your series on y2axis by specifying `seriesDefaults : {yaxis: 'y2axis'}`

Please let me know if it works.

Comment: thanks Anthony - I'll try that now, was able to just upload the before and after if that helps...I'll be back.....

Comment: this link http://www.jqplot.com/deploy/dist/examples/kcp_pyramid2.html shows that they are capable of having bars go from right to left, I just need ONLY that....

Comment: Not sure (again) but `side: 'left'` in series rendererOptions seems to be useful.

Comment: Hi Anthony - the side:left didn't do anything for me as far as the direction of the bars, but your first suggestion "seriesDefaults : {yaxis: 'y2axis'}" worked perfectly to get the list of "do's" and icons to the right.  Post that as the answer and I can vote it correct, and THANKS!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just a quick answer (I haven't tested it) :

In order to have 18 on left and 0 on right you can maybe specify the min and max value of your xaxis.

If you want the line labels to be on the right try to put your series on y2axis by specifying seriesDefaults : {yaxis: 'y2axis'}

Please let me know if it works.